# Unable to clone the repository in git_repository in bazel with ubuntu 15.10

Tags: bazel, heron

I am trying to compile the following heron branch

https://github.com/twitter/heron/tree/karthik/pexbuild

using bazel 0.3.1 in ubuntu 15.10. In the workspace, I refer to another repo containing the pex bazel rules at

https://github.com/streamlio/bazel_rules_pex

I am getting the following error (interestingly it does not occur in ubuntu14.04, ubuntu16.10, centos7 and mac). Any help will be appreciated?

`bazel build --config=ubuntu --verbose_failures heron/...
ERROR: com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.BuildFileContainsErrorsException: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'pex/pex_rules.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_pex//pex': Error cloning repository: https://github.com/streamlio/bazel_rules_pex.git: cannot open git-upload-pack caused by https://github.com/streamlio/bazel_rules_pex.git: cannot open git-upload-pack caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty caused by Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty caused by the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty.`

Comment: Why use such an old version of Bazel?

Answer (score 0):

There were many fixes and improvements in remote repositories, I'd advice you to upgrade bazel before trying anything else.